# Embedded System and Serial Flash wear issues

Tags: embedded

I am using a serial NOR flash (SPI Based) for my embedded application and also I have to implement a file system over it. That makes my NOR flash more prone to frequent erase and write cycles where having a wear level Algorithm comes into picture. I want to ask few questions regarding the same:

First, is it possible to implement a Wear Level Algorithm for Nor flash, if yes then why most of the time I find the solutions for NAND Flash and not NOR Flash?

Second, are serial SPI based low cost NAND flashes available, if yes then kindly share the part number for the same.

Third, how difficult is it to implement our own Wear Level algorithm?

Fourth, I have also read/heard that industrial grade NOR Flashes have higher erase/write cycles (in millions!!), is this understanding correct? If yes then kindly let me know the details of such SPI NOR Flash, which may also lead to avoiding implementation of wear level algorithm, if not completely then since I'm planning to implement my own wear level algorithm, it might give me a little room and ease in certain areas to implement the wear level algorithm.

The constraint to all these point is cost, I would want to have low cost solution to these issues.

Thanks in Advance

Regards

Aditya Mittal

(mittal.aditya12@gmail.com)

Comment: [Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/) is a better site to post this question, since it is not really related to programming. Also note that asking for shopping advice is as much off-topic there, as it is here.

Answer (score 6):

Implementing a wear-levelling algorithm is is not trivial, but not impossible either:

1. Your wear-levelling driver needs to know when disk blocks are no longer used by the filing system (this is known as [TRIM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRIM) support on modern SSDs).  In practice, this means you need to modify your block driver API and filing systems above it, or have the wear-levelling driver aware of the filing system's free-space map.  This second option is easy for FAT, but probably patented.
2. You need to reserve at least an erase-unit + a few allocation units to allow erase unit recycling.  Reserving more blocks will increase performance
3. You'll want a background thread to perform asynchronous erase-unit recycling
4. You'll need to test, test an test again.  When I last built one of these, we built a simulation of both flash and ran the real filing system on top it, and tortured the system for weeks.
5. There are lots and lots of patents covering aspects of wear-leveling. By the same token, there are two at least two wear-levelling layers in the Linux Kernel.

Given all of this, licensing a third-party library is probably cost-effective,

Comment: +1, especially for 3).  If there are any bugs or scenarios that can corrupt the file system, the wear-levelling will introduce more problems than it solves.

Comment: @MartinJames Oh yes! ;) Further more, finding the point at which the whole thing hoses itself is enormously difficult - unless you integrity check the entire filing system on each write.   The simulations take a while to execute!

Comment: +1 for cost effectiveness: buying a third-party solution might save money. Implemeting your own low-cost solution will almost certainly lead you to extremely expensive debugging.

Comment: Or worse, expensive failures in shipped product.

Answer (score 0):

Atmel/Adesto etc. make those little serial flash chips by the billion.  They also have loads of online docs.  I suspect that the serial flash beetles don't implement wear-levelling because of cost - the devices they are typically used in are very cheap and tend to have a limited lifetime anyway. Bulk, 4-line NAND flash that is expected to see heavier and lengthy use, (eg. SD cards), have complex, (relatively), built-in controllers that can implement wear-levelling in a transparent manner.

I no longer use one-pin interface serial flash, partly due to the wear issue.  An SD-card is cheap enough for me to use and, even if one does break, an on-site technician, (or even the customer), can easily swap it out.

Implementing a wear-levelling algo. is too expensive, both in terms of development time, (especially testing if the device has to support a file system that must not corrupt on power fail etc), and CPU/RAM for me to bother.

If your product is so cost-sensitive that you have to use serial NOR flash, I suggest that you ignore the issue.

Comment: You are misunderstanding the purpose of devices. It's not a cost issue that keeps wear-leveling out of chip level products, it's the fact that they are chip-level.  Packaged modules such as sdcards have a distinct controller in addition to the storage device - this adds wear-leveling, but limits flexbility and introduces overhead.  An application which does not match the usage assumptions made by an integrated controller can perform relatively poorly. As with anything, by doing your own you gain better control over the details of how it is done.  Both chips and modules have their applications.